# Binary star data

Tags: binary-star, contact-binaries

I was doing a project on Binary stars. I wanted data of masses, eccentricity, semi-major axis, and radial velocity. I tried many sites but I couldn't find them. Where can I download such data from?

Comment: Try searching this site!

Comment: Many Google hits on "catalogue of binary stars"

Comment: I'm curious if you could use a catalog like Hipparcos (or GAIA DR 2) to "manually" find binary stars.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for professional data you can find them on [VizieR](https://vizier.u-strasbg.fr/viz-bin/VizieR-2).
If you search for double star you will find 103 catalogues on double stars (some containing data only for a specific area in the sky).
I haven't looked at all 103 catalogues, but the [Orbits of 451 wide visual double stars : J/PAZh/45/35](https://cdsarc.unistra.fr/viz-bin/cat/J/PAZh/45/35) looks promising. (If you want to download it, go to the FTP tab.)

Comment: thank you very much very much. l have already tried VizieR, Simbad, USNO, and BDB. none of them provided masses of individual components i have to calculate it. in WDC, i could not download them.

Comment: That might be more difficult. In the catalogue I mentioned there is a mass in the table but it seems to be the combined mass. i.e. the last two columns (see https://cdsarc.unistra.fr/ftp/J/PAZh/45/35/ReadMe).

Comment: thank you. at lat i got it... [http://vizier.u-strasbg.fr/viz-bin/VizieR-4]